# Can Mathematica run of the new 2015 MacBook?

Tags: version-10

My question is in the title. I have a Macbook Pro which runs *Mathematica* smoothly, but I'd like to know if I can install *Mathematica* and run `light' notebooks on the 2015 Macbook.

Comment: Why do you think it would not? I have an acquaintance that runs *Mathematica* on  Mavericks on a four-year old Mac Mini. Surely, if that combo works, the current Macbook should be able to do it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just an unnecessary show-off.

Comment: I run it all the time on a Mid-2011 Macbook Air. It evens runs on a Raspberry Pi. The Macbook is a *lot* faster than my MBA so it'll be OK.

Answer (score 3):

Does it run? Absolutely. Will it meet your needs? We can't answer without knowing what you plan to do with Mathematica.

Factors like how much input/output you do, how much your code benefits from parallelization, and your latency tolerance will determine whether or not this laptop will suffice.

Comment: To elaborate: Mathematica is a programming language.  The question is not if Mathematica itself runs well but whether your own programs wirtten in Mathematica will run well.  (Mathematica itself does run on the very modest [Raspberry Pi computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi).)

Answer (score 3):

I have a new MacBook and I run Mathematica on it regularly.  Here's the BenchmarkReport:

[image]

Comment: For the record, top-of-the-line 15" "mid-2012" MacBook Pro Retina gets a result of 1.78 on this benchmark, for what it's worth. Not necessarily much, but it's one measuring stick for it. In particular, this benchmark would seem to not give much extra value to multiple cores, which is often realistic, but not always so.